# How to change one string from definite position using other string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I  have two strings

```
string str1 = "Hello World !"; // the position of W character is 6
string str2 = "peace";
//...
string result = "Hello peace !"; // str2 is written to str1 from position 6
```

Is there a function like this:

```
string result = str1.Rewrite(str2, 6); // (string, position)
```

**EDITED**
                                                             This "Hello World !" is just an example, I don't know whether there is "W" character in this string, what I only know are: `str1`, `str2`, position (`int`)

Comment: you should describe more in depth what your problem is. the answers below both assume different problem sets. what should rewrite do ? just insert the replacement string at this position ? or should it remove something from the original string ? what should it remove from the original string only the number of characters of the replacement string or a whole word ? what is a whole word etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@danludwigs answer is better from a code understandability perspective, however this version is a tad faster. Your explanation that you are dealing with binary data in string format (wtf bbq btw :) ) does mean that speed might be of the essence. Although using a byte array or something might be better than using a string :)

```
public static string RewriteChar(this string input, string replacement, int index)
{
  // Get the array implementation
  var chars = input.ToCharArray();
  // Copy the replacement into the new array at given index
  // TODO take care of the case of to long string?
  replacement.ToCharArray().CopyTo(chars, index);
  // Wrap the array in a string represenation
  return new string(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not, but you could create one using an extension method.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Rewrite(this string input, string replacement, int index)
    {
        var output = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        output.Append(input.Substring(0, index));
        output.Append(replacement);
        output.Append(input.Substring(index + replacement.Length));
        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then, the code you posted in your original question would work:

```
string result = str1.Rewrite(str2, 6); // (string, position)
```

Comment: a call like "Hello Worldsunderme!".Rewrite("peace", 6) would result in  the string "Hello peacesunderme!"

Comment: @StephanSchinkel, yes, that is correct. Based on the question asked, as you point out in your comment, having a different result is not a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to do this...

Because I'm a lazy ass, I would go:

```
result = str1.Substring(0, 6) + str2 + str1.Substring(12, 2);
```

or

```
result = str1.Replace("World", str2);
```

My advice would be, in Visual Studio, right click on "string" and select "Go To Definition". You will see all the methods available to the string "class".

Comment: but in this case there won't be my precious exclamation mark `" !"`